# Return different values depending on number of times a function is called

Tags: mocking, elixir

### Background

I am working in a project that uses [Mock](https://hexdocs.pm/mock/Mock.html) for testing. However I need to run a specific scenario, where the output of a function depends on the number of times said function is called.
I don't think Mock supports this, so I am trying to find out a way to conduct this test.

### Code

In this test I have a Storage module which I want to mock (it has side effects and is a boundary).
In the test, I call a function `get`, which the first time returns `nil`, then I save some data with `save` and then I call get again.

```
test_with_mock "returns OK when products list is saved into storage", Storage, [],
    [
      save: fn _table, data -> {:ok, data} end,
      get: fn
        _table, _seats_number -> {:ok, nil} # first call it returns nil
        _table, _seats_number -> {:ok, [1]} # second call should return some data
      end
    ] do
      # Arrange
      products = [
        %{"id" => 1, "gems" => 4},
        %{"id" => 3, "gems" => 4},
      ]
      products_table = :products

      # Act & Assert
      actual = Engine.save_products(products)
      expected = {:ok, :list_saved_successfully}

      assert actual == expected
      
      # First call to get returns nil because the table is empty. 
      # Then we save something into it.
      assert_called Storage.get(products_table, 4)
      assert_called Storage.save(products_table, {4, [1]})

      # Second call should return the product previously saved
      # But the mock only returns nil
      assert_called Storage.get(products_table, 4)
    end
```

The issue here is that since there is no counter, I don't have a way of returning a different output depending on the number of calls a function was called.

To be fair, Mock does offer a way to returns different outputs when the *input* is different. However, this is not the case. The input is the same, the only different is the number of invocations.

### Question

How can I achieve my goal using Mock?

Comment: It may be worth digging into how you've structured your `Storage` module and its functions.  Often when I find myself needing to maintain state in my tests, I find that I can shuffle things around a bit and achieve testability more easily.  Could you show us your `Storage` module code (or at least the significant parts of it)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. The Storage module's logic is beyond me. I do have this behaviour (or interface) that exposes the functions "save", "reset", "get" and "create".

I could, in theory, go for the Nullable Infrastructure pattern https://www.jamesshore.com/v2/blog/2018/testing-without-mocks#nullable-infrastructure

But I am not comfortable with it enough yet.

Comment: Worth saying that if I went with the Nullable Infrastructure pattern, I wouldn't need Mock at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `:meck.seq` to create a mock that returns the given values in sequence.  This relies on the fact that Mock is just a thin layer on top of [meck](https://hexdocs.pm/meck/), which allows creating mocks like this:

```
  test_with_mock "returns OK when products list is saved into storage", Storage, [],
    [
      save: fn _table, data -> {:ok, data} end,
      get: [{[:_, :_], :meck.seq([
               {:ok, nil}, # first call it returns nil
               {:ok, [1]} # second call should return some data
               ])}]
    ] do
```

That is, instead of passing an anonymous function as the implementation of the mock, pass a list of tuples, where each tuple has an "argument spec" (in this case `[:_, :_]`, to allow any two arguments) and a "return spec", for which `:meck.seq` returns a magic value that makes the mock return different values each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) to keep the mutable state. Here's the sketch:

```
defmodule MagicTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  import Mock

  setup do
    {:ok, pid} = Agent.start_link(fn -> 1 end, name: __MODULE__)
    {:ok, %{counter: pid}}
  end

  test_with_mock "test_name", %{counter: counter}, Magic, [],
    get: fn -> Agent.get_and_update(counter, fn state -> {state, state + 1} end) end do
    assert 1 == Magic.get()
    assert 2 == Magic.get()
  end
end


defmodule Magic do
  def get do
    42
  end
end
```

Your test will probably be a bit more complex, but the idea is the same.

Mock readme also [briefly explains](https://github.com/jjh42/mock#test_with_mock---with_mock-helper) how to use ExUnit context argument.